# Multi-Targeting with Conditions Causes NuGet Fail?

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, csproj

I have a project that is using NuGet packages.  It also needs to target different framework versions per build config.  I have them laid out in my csproj file something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '2018|x64'">
    <OutputPath>..\BuildFolder\2018</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '2019|x64'">
    <OutputPath>..\BuildFolder\2019</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I have more build configs than that, but those are examples where I have two different frameworks.  The issue is that when I try to batch build the project with all release configs half of them fail depending on what my current config is.  Using the two above, I can switch VS to my 2018 configuration and do a NuGet restore, then batch build both and 2018 will work and 2019 will fail with a 'Your project does not reference .NET Framework 4.7' errors.  If I then switch to the 2019 config and do a NuGet restore and then try to batch build I get the reverse; 2019 works and 2018 tells me 'Your project does not reference .NET Framework 4.6.1'.

I also tried to put in the 'TargetFrameworks' object in the csproj file but then VS just spins and spins on opening and never opens the project.

How do I get this to work and recognize it to build all configs in batch?  I suppose I could build them individually and will have to for now but that seems laborious and unnecessary...

Comment: FYI I did find links like https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/10334/your-project-is-not-referencing-the-netframeworkve.html and tried deleting the obj, bin, and vs directories but that didn't do it.  I think this is a different issue as it's two different framework versions in the same project; those I believe are all referencing the same framework version but changing it for all of them...

Comment: Something against .NET Framework 4.6.1 automatically works on 4.7, so I wonder why you even asked this question. What benefits do you want from that?

Comment: I know that is supposed to be true, but this is a class library that is for an addin to another program.  The parent program has different versions (2018, 2019, etc.) that are built against different framework versions and it seemed like there were some issues with not having the same framework targets so we started compiling multiple builds targeting multiple frameworks to match the parent.

Comment: Then probably you need to use the new SDK format projects and then set `net461` and `net47` https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/jun/22/multitargeting-and-porting-a-net-library-to-net-core-20

Comment: I thought I did that with the `<TargetFrameworks>` tag and it just spun and didn't load.  Maybe I missed something though, I will look that post ove rand try again...

Comment: Like I said, you need "new SDK format projects". That's not just hacking what you pasted above.

Comment: Are you using packages.config or the new PackageReference format to reference NuGet packages? You don't need SDK-style projects to get PackageReference features but with packages.config you can only reference one framework version per project.

Comment: Using package reference.